# Best way to implement an angular js site with multiple templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a web application using MEAN stack. I will be using two types of layouts for my pages.

Layout 1 - the full page used as the content area.

Layout 2 - layout 2 has a top banner and a sidebar. The content area is in the center.

I would like to know what is the best way to implement this using angular js. I am new to angular js development.

I hope the description explains the problem well.

Comment: have you watched tutorial videos?    Angular is a modular template based language.  So yea.... watch the videos and do the hands on demo.  (Make the Gem sales site)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do it as a single page application using ui-router for injecting template

[Example1 here...](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router)

[Example2 here...](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Angular is  modular template based language, and easily you can build singe page app.

using ui-router you can change the part of page without changing url or without refreshing.

Comment: Both your linked examples refers to the same page